# Type Inference Algorithm

Tags: java

Why  inference determines that the second argument being passed to the pick method is of type Serializable ?
Why s compiles but s1 line doesnt compile

```
static <T> T pick(T a1, T a2) { return a2; }
Serializable s = pick("d", new ArrayList<String>()); //this works
String s1= pick("d", new ArrayList<String>());//doesnt compile
```

Comment: There is no implicit conversion from `ArrayList<String>` to `String`, but both of those implement `Serializable`

Comment: Because `String` and `ArrayList` are both `Serializable`, but `ArrayList` is not type of `String`. Maybe you meant to declare second argument as `List<T> a2`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the result and both arguments must be the same type - the `T`.

In the second example, the result is a String, first parameter is a String, but the second argument is an ArrayList. String != ArrayList

In the first example, the first argument is a String (and the String implements `Serializable` interface), the second argument is an ArrayList, but List implements the Serializable. So the result can be Serializable too - it is a something common to all there 3 objects.

Answer (score 1):

For every invocation of the method, `pick()` type `T` needs to be **inferred** by the compiler.

Both calls of the `pick()` in your code snippet are so-called [*poly expressions*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.2) (i.e. sensitive to the context), because they appear in the *assignment context*. Hence, [*target type*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html#target_types) in both cases would be inferred from the *assignment context* :

- in the first case, target type is `Serializable` and compiler successfully performs *widening convection* of both arguments (`String` and `ArrayList<String>`) to `Serializable`, because it's a supertype of both;
- in the second case, target type for type parameter `T` is `String` and compiler issues a compilation error because it fails to convert the second argument of `ArrayList<String>` to `String`, these types are unrelated.